# Link in a predictable way to sub directories and files

Tags: bitbucket

I am using R to make a README.md file automatically for a repo that contains several packages.  This readme makes HTML links to each of the subdirectories.  The problem is I can't make the hyperlinks as the path is not predictable for each of the subdirectories.  Here I make the same repo in GitHub and Bitbucket but the GitHub one contains the names of the subdirectories and is rather predictable.  Bitbucket's is not.

- https://github.com/trinker/temp/blob/master/dir1/dir2/temp.Rmd
- https://bitbucket.org/trinker/temp/src/15b53574293c57269b1e4e29b5bfde25265d3ad4/dir1/dir2/temp.Rmd?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

How can I make the path in Bitbucket predictable so I can auto generate the link in the main README file?  I would expect I could do something like:

https://bitbucket.org/trinker/temp/src/dir1/dir2/temp.Rmd

but this is a dead link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which branch do you want your link to track? Add its name in place of the hash. For example, to link to that file in the 'master' branch,

https://bitbucket.org/trinker/temp/src/master/dir1/dir2/temp.Rmd

You can also link to a specific revision (which that hash represents), to a tag, or to the head:

https://bitbucket.org/trinker/temp/src/HEAD/dir1/dir2/temp.Rmd